# Custom SimpleCursorAdapter error

Tags: android, android-layout

I have ListView in my Activity, and custom SimpleCursorAdapter.
Custom SimpleCursorAdapter looks like this.

```
public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private Cursor cursor;

public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
String[] from, int[] to, Activity activity) {

    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.cursor = c;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null)
    view = View.inflate(this.activity,
         com.tour.R.layout.third_level_list_item, null);

    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

String hotelName=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TodoDbAdapter.KEY_HOTEL));
String stars = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TodoDbAdapter.KEY_ROW_STARS));
int numberOfStars = Integer.parseInt(stars);

TextView hotel = (TextView) view.findViewById(com.tour.R.id.hotel);
    if (hotel != null)
        hotel.setText(hotelName);

    ImageView[] images = new ImageView[5];
    images[0] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.tour.R.id.slika1);
    images[1] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.tour.R.id.slika2);
    images[2] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.tour.R.id.slika3);
    images[3] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.tour.R.id.slika4);
    images[4] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.tour.R.id.slika5);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++)
        images[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return view;

}
```

}

CustomSimpleCursor adapter is setted as list adapter.

Code works great, hotel name is ok, stars are ok, but problem is that after scrolling list some time, every hotel gets 5 stars, and I know that it`s true.

Any help how to manage number of stars in that listView from database.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to make sure you clean your state.
Your adapter makes stars visible as your data shows it. However it doesn't ever make them GONE/INVISIBLE when they aren't.

```
ImageView[] images = new ImageView[5];
    images[0] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.tour.R.id.slika1);
    images[1] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.tour.R.id.slika2);
    images[2] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.tour.R.id.slika3);
    images[3] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.tour.R.id.slika4);
    images[4] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.tour.R.id.slika5);

    for (ImageView image : images) {
        image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++)
        images[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Also if you want you could cache that ImageView array to avoid the look up cost of traversing the tree each time you bind a cell. Like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
       view = View.inflate(this.activity, com.tour.R.layout.third_level_list_item, null);
        ImageView[] images = new ImageView[5];
        images[0] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.tour.R.id.slika1);
        images[1] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.tour.R.id.slika2);
        images[2] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.tour.R.id.slika3);
        images[3] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.tour.R.id.slika4);
        images[4] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.tour.R.id.slika5);
        view.setTag(images);
    }

    ImageView[] images = (ImageView[]) view.getTag();
    for (ImageView image : images) {
      image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++)
      images[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return view;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never making the stars invisible. It should be something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++)
    images[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

for (int i = numberOfStars; i < 5; i++)
    images[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

All that being said:

- Consider using a `RatingBar` instead of individual stars
- Consider using the holder pattern to avoid doing all those `findViewById()` calls on every row
- Consider calling `getInt()` instead of `getString()` and then converting it to an `int` yourself
- Since this is a `CursorAdapter`, ideally you should be overriding `newView()` and `bindView()`, not `getView()`